# Work done by Force along parametric Curve.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find the work done by $\vec{G}=<yz,z,1>$ along the curve $\vec{r}=<t,\sin t,\cos t>.$ where $\displaystyle 0\leq t\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

What i try:  Here $x=t,y=\sin t,z=\cos t$

And $\displaystyle \vec{r}'(t)=<1,\cos t,-\sin t >$

And Work done  $$\int \vec{G}\cdot d\vec{r}=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\vec{G(t)}\cdot \vec{r}'(t)dt$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\bigg(\sin (2t)+1+\cos (2t)-2\sin (t)\bigg)=\frac{\pi-2}{4}$$

But answer given as $\displaystyle \frac{\pi-2}{8}$

Whats wrong with my answer. Where is extra $2$ factor in denominator gone. Please Help me . Thanks

Comment: Your answer is correct. $\delta W=\vec F \cdot\vec v dt$. It seems plausible that the "given answer" was computed with a unitary tangent vector (as $||\vec r'||=2$), but it's wrong.

Comment: Thanks Jean Claude . You are right.